# Linux: How to send udp packet to unreachable ip address

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

My program (c++ socket) receives broadcast udp datagram from another network but my program can't send udp reply to this address because "Network is unreachable" error is raised on "sendto" method.
Need to ignore netmask on reply.

Is there any socket flag to resolve this problem?

P.S.
I have simple device that works just so.

### SOLUTION

To send packet to any network you should set default gateway **with it's own ip address**.
My method:

```
int32_t setNewIp(uint8_t A_, uint8_t B_, uint8_t C_, uint8_t D_) {
    uint8_t ip_cmd[60];
    snprintf((char*) ip_cmd, sizeof (ip_cmd), "ifconfig eth0 inet %hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", A_, B_, C_, D_);
    int32_t res = system((char*) ip_cmd);
    if (res != 0) goto exit;

    snprintf((char*) ip_cmd, sizeof (ip_cmd), "route add default gw %hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", A_, B_, C_, D_);
    res = system((char*) ip_cmd);

exit:
    return res == 0 ? OK : SYSTEM_ERR;
}
```

Comment: Normally broadcasts will not transmitted over network borders, meaning a router. It seems you need to configure the router in a way that it forwards that packages. Also you need to configure the route to the remote network on your local pc

Comment: Either 1. You do not have a route set up to the remote network. 2. You have a route (e.g. the default route) that cannot reach this other network (so it gives an ICMP network unreachable reply back). So, configure a proper route to this other network. (And hopefully you're not trying to send to a broadcast address that is not local)

Comment: How do you expect this to work?
If your computer has no route to the required network, how would if know how to send it?

Comment: I receives broadcast from 255.255.255.255 and don't know about gateway. Only problem is to miss step that resolves ip->mac because mac address already resolved.

Comment: Why don't you reply the sender with unicast?

Comment: I can try to reply with broadcast... net garbadge...

Comment: Your question amounts to 'how can I reach an unreachable network'. It's a contradiction in terms.

Comment: It's unreachable on ip and reachable on ethernet level of OSI

Comment: You should provide example data: What is received, what is sent back, and what the receiver's or originator's address is.